# O que é um "dangling object/commit" no git?

Tags: git, terminologia

Meu repositório se corrompeu momentaneamente após o [apagão de ontem no Brasil](http://g1.globo.com/jornal-nacional/noticia/2018/03/apagao-atinge-todas-regioes-do-pais-so-5-estados-nao-foram-afetados.html). Consegui sanar a corrupção ([assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373010/4438007)) e resolvi rodar um `git fsck` para verificar o status do meu repositório local. Eis que ele me responde dizendo que existem *dangling commits*:

[image: git fsck apontando a existência de dangling commits]

Em uma outra oportunidade ele também me disse que haviam *dangling objects*, mas não guardei o print.

O que é um *dangling commit*? Tem alguma relação com *dangling object*?

Como essas coisas *dangling* surgem?

Comment: Não sei o quanto é "emergencial" ou se é meramente educativa a pergunta (provavelmente é isso ;) ), mas aqui tem o essencial para recuperação de dados se estiver precisando https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery - Pena que eu não posso parar pra responder oficialmente agora.

Comment: @Bacco, é educativa. Rodando algumas vezes o `prune` e o `gc --aggressive` esses objetos morreram. Fiquei com curiosidade de saber o que eram.

Comment: Porcamente falando, é coisa que ficou "órfã" ou resto de alguma operação anterior. Você pode matar os restos, mas é uma chance de recuperação de dados, no caso de situações anormais. Poderia muito bem ter acontecido de você comitar algo que não se completou, e por algum motivo precisar recuperar o dado que foi enviado e ficou nesse "universo paralelo". (novamente, é uma explicação bem precária)

Comment: @Bacco, quando estiver disponível para transformar o comentário em resposta canônica, agradeço. Imagino que um fetch mal feito/com constante interrupção da rede possa ocasionar esse problema também, junto ao commit problemático (fechar a máquina e forçar hibernação na hora do fetch é comum para mim, me perdoe... commits normalmente são mais garantidos de operar até o fim razoavelmente seguros e verificados).

Comment: Se alguém mais especializado com a terminologia do GIT o fizer, acho que sai coisa melhor do que eu fazendo. Eu só quis dar um pontapé inicial. Caso não tenha a disponibilidade de postar e ninguem o faça, quem sabe arranjo um tempinho pra estudar melhor o assunto (grande chance de eu acabar não fazendo) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os **dangling objects** são dados que estão guardados no repositório mas não podem ser alcançáveis por meios normais, pois nenhuma branch ou tag apontam para eles.

É natural a existência destes objetos em seu repositório com o passar do tempo, pois são meios do Git assegurar que você não perca algumas informações mesmo que cometa algum erro ou se arrependa de alguma ação.

Existem dois tipos de dados *dangling*: **blob** e **commit**.

Os *dangling **commits*** são commits quem pertenciam a alguma branch ou tag, mas esta branch/tag foi removida do repositório. O Git mantém estes commits dentro do repositório, mas eles não são naturalmente alcançáveis.

Os *dangling **blobs*** são dados que estão no *index* (*staging area*) mas que o usuário nunca os commitou. Eles também tem um *hash* pois quando você faz um `git add` o git já calcula o `SHA-1` do conteúdo.

Contudo, estes objetos não ficam para sempre no repositório. O Git executa, de tempos em tempos, um `git gc` para fazer uma [limpeza](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) e otimização no repositório, removendo objetos que encontram-se neste estado e que sejam mais antigos que 2 semanas.

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente, como ouve o apagão na qual você falou e você conseguiu restaurar os arquivos, o *dangling commits* ou *dangling objects*, é o termo na qual o log se monstra como algum arquivo da *tree* ou objeto que foi corrompido e foi restaurado com sucesso. Assim no log aparece *dangling commits* ou *dangling objects*.