# O que é um objeto frouxo?

Tags: git

De vez em quando a minha ferramenta de versionamento me diz que há algo de frouxo no meu galho.

[image: Hang loose]

Felizmente a ferramenta sempre me aperta os frouxos, mas fica a curiosidade. Por que o Git me afrouxa objetos? Há algo que eu possa fazer para que meu galho não fique tão flácido?

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta não sobre _loose_, mas sobre _dangling_. Acho que poderiam ser perguntas correlatas. Eis ela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285851/64969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

Um objeto "frouxo" é armazenado *as is*, sem estar "amarrado" em outro para se definir. Ele é "frouxo" dentro do repositório. Um arquivo de informação primária.

---

Não achei a informação *direta* sobre o assunto. Entretanto, na [documentação oficial do Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) (navegando [a partir daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709910/4438007)) há uma menção a objetos frouxos quando ele fala sobre os *internals* do empacotamento (grifo meu):

> You have two nearly identical 22K objects on your disk (each compressed to approximately 7K). Wouldn’t it be nice if Git could **store one of them in full** but then the **second object only as the delta** between it and the first?
>
> It turns out that it can. The **initial format** in which Git saves objects on disk **is called a “loose” object format**. However, occasionally Git packs up several of these objects into a single binary file called a “packfile” in order to save space and be more efficient. Git does this if you have too many loose objects around, if you run the `git gc`  command manually, or if you push to a remote server.

Em tradução livre (mantendo os meus grifos):

> Você tem dois objetos de 22K praticamente idênticos no seu disco (cada um comprimido para aproximadamente 7K). Não seria legal se o Git conseguisse **armazenar apenas um completamente** mas o **segundo objeto como um delta** entre ele e o primeiro?
>
> Acontece que ele pode. A **forma inicial** em que o Git salva o objeto em disco **é chamada de formato "frouxo" de objeto"". Entretanto, ocasionalmente o Git vai empacotar diversos desses objetos em um único arquivo binário chamado "packfile" para economizar espaço em disco e ser mais eficiente. Git faz isso se você tiver muitos objetos frouxos por aí, se você rodar o comando `git gc` na mão ou se você empurrar para um servidor remoto.

Então, através desse excerto da documentação, podemos inferir que objetos **frouxos** são aqueles que não são armazenados de maneira **comprimida**. Uma maneira de se ver é como contraponto de *amarrado*, um objeto *solto*. Isso é, inclusive, de certo modo apoiado pela [definição de *loose* no Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose#Adjective):

> Adjective
>
> loose (comparative looser, superlative loosest)
>
> 1. Not fixed in place tightly or firmly.
>
>    - This wheelbarrow has a *loose* wheel.

Em que indica como tradução para *not tightly fixed*:

> Portuguese: [frouxo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frouxo#Portuguese) (pt) m, [solto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solto#Portuguese) (pt) m

Portanto, um objeto "frouxo"/"solto" não necessita estar "amarrado" fortemente em outro objeto para se definir, enquanto que outro objeto pode estar amarrado em um objeto solto ou em outro amarrado para se definir.

---

Aparentemente, não há muitas relações entre objetos [*dangling*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285851/64969) e *loose*.