# Como pegar o branch original?

Tags: git

Sempre que crio um branch `X`, crio ele a partir de outro.
Tem como saber a partir de qual branch criei o branch `X`?

Comment: eu ia responder mas [essa questão do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch) tem muitas alternativas.. melhor não limitar uma pra você =p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>*Esta é uma tradução/adaptação das respostas [desta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204), seguindo as [recomendações da Central de Ajuda sobre a tradução de conteúdos para o português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english).*</sup>

---

Os *commits* do Git formam um [DAG (sigla em inglês para "Grafo Acíclico Dirigido")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Os branches são apenas *labels* ("nomes"/"apelidos") que apontam para *commits* específicos deste grafo. Por isso, a relação entre dois *branches* diferentes pode variar com o tempo, mas a relação entre dois *commits* não muda. Ex:

```
---o---1  <- foo
        \
         2---3---7  <- bar
              \
               4
                \
                 5---6  <- baz
```

Olhando este histórico, parece que `baz` foi criado a partir de uma versão antiga do *branch* `bar`. Mas e se apagarmos `bar`?

```
---o---1  <- foo
        \
         2---3
              \
               4
                \
                 5---6  <- baz
```

Agora parece que `baz` foi criado a partir de `foo`. Mas os ancestrais de `baz` não mudaram, nós apenas removemos o *label* `bar` (e o commit `7` desaparece do histórico porque não é possível chegar a ele por nenhum *branch* existente - ele é chamado de [*dangling commit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285851/112052)).

Mas e se adicionarmos um novo *label* ao commit `4`?

```
---o---1  <- foo
        \
         2---3
              \
               4  <- quux
                \
                 5---6  <- baz
```

Agora parece que `baz` foi criado a partir de `quux`. Novamente, os ancestrais não mudaram, apenas os *labels*.

Enfim, se a pergunta que queremos responder é "*o commit `6` é um descendente do commit `3`?*" (assumindo que `3` e `6` são nomes de *commits* válidos), então a resposta é "sim", **independente dos *branches* `baz` e `quux` existirem**.

Agora se a pergunta for "*a partir de qual branch `baz` foi criado?*", não há uma maneira confiável de saber. No exemplo acima, poderia ser de `foo`, de `quux` ou de um *branch* que já foi apagado. Você até poderia [verificar a data de criação](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255416) de `foo` ou `quux`, para tentar descobrir se eles já existiam quando `baz` foi criado, ou no caso de um *branch* que foi apagado, [verificar no `reflog` se ele existia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640806) naquele momento. Mas não é um processo tão simples, como você pode ver nos respectivos links.

---

Uma outra maneira de atacar este problema é mudá-lo para: "encontre o *commit* mais próximo do meu *branch* atual que pertence a outro *branch*, e me diga que *branch* é esse".

O comando é:

```
git show-branch -a \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' \
| sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

Ele funciona assim:

1. Mostra um histórico de todos os *commits*, incluindo *branches* remotos
2. Ancestrais do *commit* atual são indicados por um asterisco, então ignoramos o restante.
3. Ignore também os *commits* do *branch* atual.
4. O primeiro resultado será o *branch* ancestral mais próximo. Ignore os outros resultados.
5. Os nomes dos *branches* são mostrados [entre colchetes]. Ignore os colchetes, e tudo fora deles.
6. Às vezes o nome do *branch* possui `~#` ou `^#` para indicar quantos *commits* há entre os *branches* envolvidos. Também estamos ignorando isso.

Por exemplo, se tivermos este histórico:

```
 A---B---D  <- master
      \
       \
        C---E---I  <- develop
             \
              \
               F---G---H  <- topic
```

Ao rodá-lo a partir do *commit* `H`, a resposta será `develop`, e se rodarmos a partir de `I`,  o resultado será `master`. Lembrando que o resultado pode variar com o tempo, conforme *branches* vão sendo criados ou apagados.

Código disponível [neste *gist*](https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741).

---

Se quiser, você também pode criar um *alias* para o comando acima. Basta adicionar no seu `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    parent = "!git show-branch -a | grep '*' | grep -v \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\\[\\(.*\\)\\].*/\\1/' | sed 's/[\\^~].*//' #"
```

Depois basta rodar:

```
git parent
```

---

Se você quiser saber qual *commit* é o ancestral comum entre dois *branches*, pode fazer algo como:

```
git merge-base topic develop
```

O resultado será o *commit* `E` (o ponto em comum entre os *branches* `develop` e `topic`). Pode não ser a resposta ideal, mas já dá algumas pistas de que talvez o *branch* tenha sido criado a partir dali.